# Why was my flag asking a moderator to migrate my own question declined?

Tags: support, flags, asking-questions, migration

I posted (by mistake) the following question about Linux to Stack Overflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/37095545

So, I decided to flag my question and ask a moderator to move it to a proper site, but it was declined and I think the moderator's explanation wasn't helpful enough. Searching about Stack Exchange migration process, I found this question:

[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

It states...

> If you don't have 3,000 reputation, the site isn't in the list of available migration targets, or the question got closed without being
>   migrated, you can flag the question for moderator attention and
>   request that they migrate it for you. Simply explain in the reason
>   which site you want it to be migrated. (Please select one site; don't
>   list all possible sites it could go to.)

I don't have 3,000 reputation.

What is really wrong with my flag?

Comment: That question has no answers. Why do you need a moderator to migrate it for you? Just delete it and repost it to the correct site yourself.

Comment: I agree with you. It was my first thought when I noticed my mistake, but a comment by @shellter made my mind. At that moment, it sounded to be the right thing to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You flagged the post with

> Could you move this question to superuser.com OR unix.stackexchange.com?

There are several things wrong here:

- You didn't pick a site; please don't ask the moderators to pick, we have too many flags and too little time. The FAQ you link to says so:

  > Please select one site; don't list all possible sites it could go to.
- Super User is a *standard flagging option*, use that if you are not sure. This is why I declined your flag with:

  > Super User is part of the standard migration path; use that instead of flagging for moderator attention.
- If you don't have the reputation to reach the 'Super User' option, **at the very least tell us**. We can't see your reputation level in the flag dialog, so we generally will decline such flags unless this is made clear.

I'm not happy that the FAQ tells you to flag for this reason however; there are usually more than enough 3k+ users around to take care of such migrations. If there are no answers, then the better option is to just close a question (migration should only be applied if the question really is off-topic on Stack Overflow) and comment that the OP may want to repost on the other site. That is almost always the faster path for the OP.

Note that I didn't even realise it was your own post you were flagging here; since you are the OP, you can just delete the question and repost it on another site, practically instantly.